# Puppeteer: Using page.querySelectorAll() is Not a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

I'm working on a Puppeteer script that takes a screenshot of all the elements on a page. It works, but I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
const elements = await page.querySelectorAll('*');
```

**(node:31953) TypeError: page.querySelectorAll is not a function**

Only this works:

```
const elements = await page.$$('*');
```

I'm trying to avoid jQuery syntax. How can I make querySelectorAll('*') work? Here is the full script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

( async() => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
        headless: true } );
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto( 'https://www.google.com' );

// Get a list of all elements. Why can't I use page.querySelectorAll('*')?
const elements = await page.$$('*');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  try {
    // get screenshot of a particular element
    await elements[i].screenshot({path: `${i}.png`})
  } catch(e) {
    // if element is 'not visible', spit out error and continue
    console.log(`couldnt take screenshot of element with index: ${i}. Because: `,  e)
  }
}
await browser.close();
} )();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check `page.$$` in [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1), you'll find that actually, puppeteer runs `querySelectorAll()` on `document`.

But if you'd like to

> avoid jQuery syntax. How can I make querySelectorAll('*') work

Solution would be to access page's document and execute there `querySelectorAll()`

```
const allElems = await page.evaluate(() => {
   // Note 1: here you can use querySelectorAll()
   // Note 2: eval can't return non-serializable data, so, you need to JSON.stringify() it to receive what you need. 
   return JSON.stringify(document.querySelectorAll())
})
```

More about [evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.11.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

To sum up, it's O.K. to use `$$` selector, because it's not the jQuery style, but a [DOM Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) one.

Comment: Tried running return JSON.stringify(document.querySelectorAll('*')) and got querySelectorAll() is not a function.